# XMLHttpRequest posts not being push

Tags: javascript, http, request, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to o-authenticate a user using the Google Platform Library on client side and the `google-auth-library` on back-end. Using the following code as I am following the [official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id"
  content="myuserid.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script>
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://mysubdomain.openshiftapps.com/oauth/google/redirect');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function() {
      console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
  }
</script>
```

I don't see any post request issued from the client side.

Using Chrome or Internet explorer debugging tools, only showing requests to load resources, `platform.js` among them.

ps: myuserid and mysubdomain are replaced by their values.

Comment: No errors in the console?

Comment: you have the reason, it showed something like: "Cookies are not enabled in current environment." error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed" but I didn't pay attention at first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was a cookie authorization problem. I authorized google.com, accounts.google.com and the domain name of my web application. all is back to normal now.